# primefaces: Execute action before update in commandlink

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a Dialog and a CommandLink which shows this dialog. In this Dialog i display values which has created during the action (or propertyListener) of the command link. But because the update is executed before the action, the variables are not set.

```
<p:commandLink update="@form:myDialog" action="#{myBean.setText('text')}"
oncomplete="myDialog.show()">
</p:commandLink>
....
<p:dialog widgetVar="myDialog"  modal="true">
      <p:inputText value="#{myBean.text}" />
</p:dialog>
```

Is it possible to execute an action before the update is done?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: I changed the description. There is no exception and no stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dialog will update you haven't specified the Id attribute of the dialog

```
<p:commandLink update="myDialog" action="#{myBean.setText('text')}"
     oncomplete="myDialog.show()">
</p:commandLink>

<p:dialog Id="myDialog" widgetVar="myDialog"  modal="true">
    <p:inputText value="#{myBean.text}" />
</p:dialog>
```

This will help you .

But what i prefer is use an outputpanel

```
<p:commandLink update="myDialogPanel " actionlistner="#{myBean.setText('text')}"
     oncomplete="myDialog.show()">
</p:commandLink>

<p:dialog Id="myDialog" widgetVar="myDialog"  modal="true">
   <p:outputPanel Id=myDialogPanel >
    <p:inputText value="#{myBean.text}" />
   </p:outputPanel>
</p:dialog>
```

or you can update the dialog from managedBean and show the dialog. This is helpful if you get any error at your managedBean method your dialog is not show.

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("myDialogPanel");
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("myDialog.show();");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can open the Dialog from ManagedBean itself.

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute(myDialog.show());
```

[RequestContext](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html) can be used to Execute any javascript from ManagedBean.
You can also update the components from Managed Bean using [RequestContext](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html)'s [Update](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html#update%28java.lang.String%29)
method.

```
 RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("COMPONENT_ID");
```